# What is wrong with this class definition?

Tags: c#

I have a class like this:

```
class connect:IDisposable
{
   public void OpenChannel(SqlConnection ch)
   {
     ch.ConnectionString=".....";
     ch.Open();
   }
   public void Dispose()
  {
  }
}
```

And another class like this:

```
public Cust
{
   SqlConnection channel=new SqlConnection();
   SqlCommand command=new SqlCommand();

   public void Method()
   {
       using(connect con=new connect())
         {
         con.OpenChannel(channel);
         command.connection=channel;
         .....
         ....
         ....
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
   }
```

But when I run ExcuteNotQuery() there is an error: "no open connection"
So what is wrong?

Comment: Not technically wrong, but `connect` should start with a capital C.

Comment: it would help if you posted a working example that shows the problem extracted from *the real code*

Comment: This code won't even compile - so it's possible you've mis-transcribed the bug anyway... can you paste extracts from the actual code?

Comment: yeah the 'class' keyword is missing but it shouldn't compile without it.

Comment: On a design level - presumably `Cust` is a *customer* - not sure that a *customer* style entity usually has it's own connection/command fields. Unrelated to the issue - I'm just saying...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Cust
{
   SqlConnection channel=new SqlConnection();
   SqlCommand command;//=new SqlCommand();

   public void Method()
   {
       using(connect con=new connect())
         {
         con.OpenChannel(channel);
         //command.connection=channel;

         // create command from open connection
         command = channel.CreateCommand();
         .....
         ....
         ....
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
   }
```